# Remove CSS Grid vertical cell spacing

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm looking for a way to align CSS Grid cells into two columns with some of the cells aligned left and some right but without any vertical gaps.

I have [mocked the issue in codepen](https://codepen.io/dclawson/pen/GRRagyB). I am trying to get the right column only to have no vertical spacing, is this possible?

```
.grid {
  width: 768px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);

  .cell {
    background: tomato;
    margin-bottom: 8px;

    &.a {
      grid-column: 1/6;
    }

    &.b {
      grid-column: 7/13;
    }
  }
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This is the space i'm trying to remove so the content sits directly underneath:

[image: css grid example]

Comment: related:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200955/8620333 .. scroll and you will find the a CSS grid solution

Comment: Thanks for the link but i'm struggling to find where the vertical spacing is removed?

Comment: set margin to  0 to your .cell classes. You have a 8px margin

Comment: Updated my question to show the space i'm trying to remove.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `grid-row: span 3` on the img element and `grid-row : span 1` on the b row

[Here is the Codepen](https://codepen.io/usamaashraf82/pen/oNNRxjM) for example